# Hide parent container if children are set to display none

Tags: javascript

Not sure what I'm missing here, but trying to hide the entire container for links `parent-container` if the anchor links inside it are set to inline `display: none`

I've tried checking if the style is none with
`[...document.querySelectorAll(".parent-container a")].map(item => item.style.display == "none" && document.querySelectorAll(".parent-container").style = "display: none")`

But can't get it to check correctly.

```js
const parentContainer = document.querySelector(".parent-container [data-filter]");

const toggleViews = function(filterName) {
  parentContainer.forEach($el => {
    if ($el.dataset.filter == filterName || filterName == 'show-all') {
      $el.style.display = "initial";
    } else {
      $el.style.cssText = "display:none!important";
    }
  });
};
```

```css
section {
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<section class="parent-container">
  <div>
    <div class="">
      <header>
        <h3>heading</h3>
      </header>
      <div class="col-w1">

        <a href="#" class="" style="display: none;" data-filter="car">
          <div class="col-item">
            <img src="#" alt="">Test
          </div>
        </a>

        <a href="#" class="" style="display: none;" data-filter="boat">
          <div class="col-item">
            <img src="#" alt="">Test
          </div>
        </a>

        <a href="#" class="" style="display: none;" data-filter="house">
          <div class="col-item">
            <img src="#" alt="">Test
          </div>
        </a>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>

<section class="parent-container">
  <div>
    <div class="">
      <header>
        <h3>heading</h3>
      </header>
      <div class="col-w1">

        <a href="#" class="" style="display: block;" data-filter="house">
          <div class="col-item">
            <img src="#" alt="">Test
          </div>
        </a>

        <a href="#" class="" style="display: block;" data-filter="car">
          <div class="col-item">
            <img src="#" alt="">Test
          </div>
        </a>

        <a href="#" class="" style="display: block;" data-filter="boat">
          <div class="col-item">
            <img src="#" alt="">Test
          </div>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Root cause on the problem, though, is that the selector `.parent-container a` picks up all of the anchor tags in the doc, since they are all ancestors of either of the two .parent-container's. Use an id per section and query that.

Comment: @danh - can you provide an example of what you're talking about?

Comment: I began to answer when I made the comment, but decided that @pilchard's answer had the essential idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a nested loop, the outer iterating over each `parent-container` and the inner over each `a` element, here using [`NodeList.forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList/forEach) for the outer loop and [`Array.every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) over the `a` elements queried from each `container` (with [`getElementsByTagName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getElementsByTagName) in this case).

```js
document.querySelectorAll(".parent-container").forEach(container => {
  const aElements = [...container.getElementsByTagName("a")];
  if (aElements.every(element => element.style.display === "none")) {
    container.style.display = 'none'
  } else {
    container.style.display = 'block'
  }
});
```

```css
section{
border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<section class="parent-container"><div><div class=""><header><h3>heading</h3></header><div class="col-w1"><a href="#" class="" style="display: none;"><div class="col-item"><img src="#" alt="">Test</div></a><a href="#" class="" style="display: none;"><div class="col-item"><img src="#" alt="">Test</div></a><a href="#" class="" style="display: none;"><div class="col-item"><img src="#" alt="">Test</div></a></div></div></div></section><section class="parent-container"><div><div class=""><header><h3>heading</h3></header><div class="col-w1"><a href="#" class="" style="display: block;"><div class="col-item"><img src="#" alt="">Test</div></a><a href="#" class="" style="display: block;"><div class="col-item"><img src="#" alt="">Test</div></a><a href="#" class="" style="display: block;"><div class="col-item"><img src="#" alt="">Test</div></a></div></div></div></section>
```

**Edit**

In response to your more complete snippet here is an extended example. You are still not addressing the multiple levels necessary to achieve what you need (as noted by @danh in the comments as well). You need to address each `parent-container` and then the relevant children of each individually. The example below first uses your logic to filter the children of each container, and then checks if they have all been hidden or not. I've implemented it with a `.hidden` class instead of inline CSS but you can adapt as you see fit.

```js
// query only the parent-containers
const parentContainers = document.querySelectorAll(".parent-container");

function toggleViews(filterName) {
  for (const container of parentContainers) {
    // query relevant children
    const elements = [...container.querySelectorAll("[data-filter]")];

    // hide filtered elements
    for (const element of elements) {
      if (element.dataset.filter === filterName || filterName === 'show-all') {
        element.classList.remove('hidden');
      } else {
        element.classList.add('hidden');
      }
    }

    // hide parent if all children are hidden
    if (elements.every(element => element.classList.contains('hidden'))) {
      container.classList.add('hidden');
    } else {
      container.classList.remove('hidden');
    }
  };
};

document.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  if (e.target.nodeName === 'BUTTON'){
    toggleViews(e.target.textContent.toLowerCase().replace(' ', '-'));
  }
});
```

```css
section {
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<button type="button" class="filter">Boat</button>
<button type="button" class="filter">House</button>
<button type="button" class="filter">Car</button>
<button type="button" class="filter">Show all</button>

<section class="parent-container">
  <div>
    <div class="">
      <header>
        <h3>Section 1</h3>
      </header>
      <div class="col-w1">

        <a href="#" class="" data-filter="car">
          <div class="col-item">
            <img src="#" alt="">Car
          </div>
        </a>

        <a href="#" class="" data-filter="bicycle">
          <div class="col-item">
            <img src="#" alt="">Bicycle
          </div>
        </a>

        <a href="#" class="" data-filter="house">
          <div class="col-item">
            <img src="#" alt="">House
          </div>
        </a>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>

<section class="parent-container">
  <div>
    <div class="">
      <header>
        <h3>Section 2</h3>
      </header>
      <div class="col-w1">

        <a href="#" class="" data-filter="shed">
          <div class="col-item">
            <img src="#" alt="">Shed
          </div>
        </a>

        <a href="#" class="" data-filter="car">
          <div class="col-item">
            <img src="#" alt="">Car
          </div>
        </a>

        <a href="#" class="" data-filter="boat">
          <div class="col-item">
            <img src="#" alt="">Boat
          </div>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: I updated my question with my full script. Tried implementing your solution, but was seeing the cards disappearing all together. Not sure how to implement your solution with my updated code.